# SharePoint 2013 Workflows Auto Disappear and Auto Reappear 4 hours later

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have about 25 SharePoint 2013 workflows and 10 2010 workflows on SharePoint Designer 2013.

For a 4 hour period, all 25 Sharepoint 2013 workflows disappeared but the 10 2010 workflows remained.  Without any troubleshooting, all 25 workflows reappeared and then ran themselves for any auto-runs that it missed during the period that they were missing.

Any idea what caused this?  Workflows are operating fine now but just for the future.

Comment: Try to install Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 (KB2817441) 64-Bit Edition https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=42009